# Did Newton know that light has no inertia?

Tags: visible-light, photons, history, inertia

Newton studied a lot about optics and gravitation. Did he realize to some extent that light is a massless particle? How does his theory explain the bending of light due to a gravitational field?

Comment: Does [this Wikipedia section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpuscular_theory_of_light#:~:text=In%20the%20book%2C%20Newton%20argued,to%20travel%20in%20straight%20lines.) answer your question?

Comment: What do you mean by *"light has no inertia"*? Light is massless, but it certainly has momentum. $E=pc$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on the [hsm.se]

Answer (score 3):

If he could have measured light pressure, he would have concluded that light *does* have inertia! Note also, while massless photons are the current fashion, that's dependent on how you define mass. Using "relativistic mass", the definition consistent with the famous $E=mc^2$, photons have mass since they have energy. You can construct working models from either mass definition: they don't make conflicting predictions as long as you use consistent math.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that Newton had no conception of light interacting with gravity. Further, gravity is so weak in any space-times where Einstein's gravity is approximately Newtonian that there is no effect on trajectory. (There are quantum effects on light in low gravity, but that is another thing altogether)

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus *gravity is so weak in any space-times where Einstein's gravity is approximately Newtonian that there is no effect on trajectory* The deflection of starlight by the Sun was one of the first famous tests of Einstein’s gravity. I would call that an “effect on trajectory”.

Comment: @Ghoster I don't consider the gravity near the sun or other massive star as being a good example of Newtonian gravity. I would say that the gravity in an Earth based laboratory or somewhere in an empty void of space is more like it. However, it is good that you bring it up, since a good deal of celestial mechanics has been done using the Newtonian concepts.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus The dimensionless parameter that determines whether Newtonian gravity is a good approximation at the surface of the Sun is the Schwarzschild radius of the Sun divided by the radius of the Sun. This is a small number, so Newtonian gravity is accurate there, at least for massive particles.

Comment: @Ghoster Oh, I see. Whether or Newtonian gravity holds is not merely an opinion of mine based on whether or not it would be easy to devise a GR experiment. Thanks!